# Catch-22 For Authorize.net Customer Profiles: Cannot create profile without adding credit card - violates PCI

Tags: xml, authorize.net

Custom Profiles API purports to allow the customer to enter their payment details and save it on Authorize.net without the credit card number hitting our servers to maintain PCI compliance. However, in order to create a customer profile, it requires a credit card number in the first place! I want to access the hosted form, but it requires a customer profile id. To create a customer profile id, I have to create a customer profile. To create a customer profile, it requires a credit card number. The API only uses server-side languages, so that would mean the credit card number is hitting our servers.

I tried to edit the sample request in the API reference and remove `<payment>`, but when submitted, it gave an error.

I thought I should be able to create a blank customer profile, display the form, allow the user to enter their payment details, save to Authorize.net, then fetch the payment details later during the subscription billing period.

https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-create-customer-profile

```
<createCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
   <merchantAuthentication>
     <name>5GwYqmx58k</name>
     <transactionKey>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</transactionKey>
    </merchantAuthentication>
   <profile>
     <merchantCustomerId>Merchant_Customer_ID</merchantCustomerId>
     <description>Profile description here</description>
     <email>customer-profile-email@here.com</email>
     <paymentProfiles>
       <customerType>individual</customerType>
      </paymentProfiles>
    </profile>
    <validationMode>testMode</validationMode>
  </createCustomerProfileRequest>
```

> Response: E00029 : Payment information is required.

Documentation: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/customer_profiles.html

Comment: It doesn't allow you to create profiles without hitting your servers. It allows you to create profiles so you don't  have to store that data. Big difference between the two.

Comment: So credit card numbers flowing through your server is PCI compliant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCI DSS allows card data to pass through a merchant's server, however the merchant is then responsible to ensure their environment is fully PCI DSS compliant.  To reduce your PCI Scope, and avoid having sensitive data pass through your server, you can create customer profiles using Accept.js or Accept Customer.

https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept.html

To create a customer profile without payment details, use the following without payment or validation object:

```html
<createCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"> 
   <merchantAuthentication>
     <name>*</name>
     <transactionKey>*</transactionKey>
    </merchantAuthentication>
   <profile>
     <merchantCustomerId>Merchant_Customer_ID</merchantCustomerId>
     <email>customer-profile-email99@here.com</email>
    </profile>
  </createCustomerProfileRequest>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you read the question or understand the question, but that's exactly what I'm trying to do. The problem is "For first-time customers, you must create a new profile using the createCustomerProfileRequest method." But to create a customer profile, you need to pass a credit card number.

Comment: @Chloe I updated answer with a sample xml request that removes payment and validation object, allowing you to create just the parent customer profile.  You can then use Accept Customer to add payment details.

Comment: Ah, so remove `<paymentProfiles>` and `<validationMode>`. Got it. That was successful! But I wonder if they will be able to select `<customerType>business</customerType>` later?